# Add two string properties together inside the same object (Uncaught ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this:

```js
var test = {
    hello: "one",
    world: "two",
    all: hello + world
}

$('h1').text("Test > all: " + test.all);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
```

Why do I get the following error when it is clearly defined above?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined

I have tried adding `this` but no luck.

Comment: It's because the object doesn't exist yet at the point you call both `hello` and `world` to set the `all` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because you try to set "all" from undefined variables. Use a getter for what you try to do :

```
var test = {
  hello: "one",
  world: "two",
  get all() { return this.hello + this.world; }
}

$('h1').text("Test > all: " + test.all);
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, no ecma-262 5.1

Comment: @HamletHakobyan unless you are running IE8 and +2 years old browsers, this is a compatible implementation (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get))

Comment: You are right, the simple form (without expressions for a computed property name) was introduced in ES5.1. +1

Answer (score 2):

It's because the object doesn't exist yet at the point you call both `hello` and `world` to set the `all` property. If you need this behaviour, define `all` as a function so that it is executed after the object has been defined:

```js
var test = {
    hello: "one",
    world: "two",
    all: function() {
        return this.hello + this.world
    }
}

$('h1').text("Test > all: " + test.all());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in two steps:

```
var test = {
    hello: "one",
    world: "two"
}

test.all = test.hello + test.world;
```